# Ray tracer reflections grainy

Tags: c++, graphics, 3d, rendering, raytracing

I just implemented reflections in my ray tracer, here is the code that handles the reflections, however i have all my code uploaded to a [github repository](https://github.com/MrCappuccino/Tracey/blob/master/src/main.cpp#L77) for better reading:

```
Color finalColor = closestObjectMaterial.GetColor() * AMBIENTLIGHT; // Add ambient light to the calculation

// Reflections
if(closestObjectMaterial.GetSpecular() > 0 && closestObjectMaterial.GetSpecular() <= 1)
{
    Vector scalar = closestObjectNormal * (closestObjectNormal.Dot(intersectingRayDir.Negative()));
    Vector resultantReflection = intersectingRayDir.Negative() + ((scalar + (intersectingRayDir)) * 2);
    Vector reflectionDirection = resultantReflection.Normalize();

    Ray reflectionRay(intersectionRayPos, resultantReflection);

    // determine what the ray intersects with first
    std::vector<FPType> reflectionIntersections;
    for(auto sceneObject : sceneObjects)
    {
        reflectionIntersections.push_back(sceneObject->GetIntersection(reflectionRay));
    }

    int closestObjectWithReflection = ClosestObjectIndex(reflectionIntersections);

    if(closestObjectWithReflection != -1)
    {
        // reflection ray missed everthing else
        if(reflectionIntersections[closestObjectWithReflection] > TOLERANCE)
        {
            // determine the position and direction at the point of intersection with the reflection ray
            // the ray only affects the color if it reflected off something
            Vector reflectionIntersectionPosition = intersectionRayPos + (resultantReflection * (reflectionIntersections[closestObjectWithReflection]));
            Vector reflectionIntersectionRayDirection = resultantReflection;
            Color reflectionIntersectionColor = GetColorAt(reflectionIntersectionPosition, reflectionIntersectionRayDirection, sceneObjects, closestObjectWithReflection, lightSources);
            finalColor += (reflectionIntersectionColor * closestObjectMaterial.GetReflection());
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting these grainy artifacts on all reflections (this is a 16k resolution render zoomed in):

[image]

However it's even more obvious on lower resolutions like 1920x1080:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that the reflection Ray hits itself. I didn't recompile the code to confirm this. You might try adding some offset to the start position of reflection ray.

```
Vector offset = resultantReflection * 0.001;
Ray reflectionRay(intersectionRayPos + offset, resultantReflection);
```

Comment: I ended up using this, the resultantReflection needs to be normalized too. `Vector offset = reflectionDirection * 0.001;  Ray reflectionRay(intersectionRayPos + offset, resultantReflection);`

Comment: In your comments you've added

// Offset is added to cancel out the grainyness effect in the reflections

The actual problem is, your rays that start from reflecting object A is considered hitting itself as it is the nearest object from the ray start position. So to avoid this we are starting the ray slightly away from the surface of the object A.